# How to prevent reload of facebook-like button

Tags: asp.net

I have a fb-like button on top of a Masterpage and wrapped a updatepanel around the Contentplaceholder.

The updatepanel is function, but the fb button reload every time. Anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: Can you add some code to make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Code:
.
.

```
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nb_NO/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

```
<div class="fb-like" style="float: right; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px;" data-href="http://www.xxxxxx.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="true" data-font="verdana" data-action="recommend"></div>
```

.
.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMainContent" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 5px;" Height="450px" ScrollBars="Auto">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

The contentpages function with the updatepanel, but the fb-like button flicker every partial update